# Connecting two layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to connect Footer with userdata, but app is crashing. Can anyone help with this?

Login class :

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    EditText fullname, mobilenumber, occupation;
    Button save;
    ImageView ad1, ad2, ad3, ad4, ad5, ad6;
    HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView1;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.userdata);
        fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        mobilenumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);
        occupation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.occupation);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        ad1 = (ImageView) ad1.findViewById(R.id.ad1);
        ad2 = (ImageView) ad2.findViewById(R.id.ad2);
        ad3 = (ImageView) ad3.findViewById(R.id.ad3);
        ad4 = (ImageView) ad4.findViewById(R.id.ad4);
        ad5 = (ImageView) ad5.findViewById(R.id.ad5);
        ad6 = (ImageView) ad6.findViewById(R.id.ad6);
        horizontalScrollView1 = (HorizontalScrollView) horizontalScrollView1
                .findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
    }
}
```

fullname,mobilenumber, occupation Button save, these from main layout and ImageView ad1,ad2,ad3,ad4,ad5,ad6;  horizontalScrollView1, these are from footerlayout.
I'm calling footer.layout from main layout. Like this :

```
 <include layout="@layout/footer" />
```

Footer layout is visible from main layout but app is crashing. Dont know why !!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip" >

<!-- Full Name Label -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Full Name"
    android:textColor="#372c24"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/fullname"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:singleLine="true" />
<!-- Email Label -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mobile number"
    android:textColor="#372c24"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mobile"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="phone" />


<!-- Password Label -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Occupation"
    android:textColor="#372c24"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/occupation"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    tools:ignore="TextFields" />

<!-- Register Button -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSave"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
    android:text="Save"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />    
<include layout="@layout/footer" /> </LinearLayout><!-- Registration Form Ends -->
```

log cat

```
    01-16 15:48:54.048: E/AndroidRuntime(9072): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mixorg.parsefooter/com.mixorg.parsefooter.Login}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2503)
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     at com.mixorg.parsefooter.Login.onCreate(Login.java:22)
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
01-16 15:48:54.058: E/AndroidRuntime(9072):     ... 11 more
01-16 15:48:54.088: E/SemcCheckin(9072): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
```

Comment: Post your main layout.xml

Comment: Could we get a stack trace of your crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Take your **footer_lay** as include layout id like below

**Xml**

```
<include 
   android:id="@+id/footer_lay"
   layout="@layout/footer" />
```

**Java**

And Refer footer_lay as `LinearLayout` and view as your footer lay  `ImageView` as `footer_lay.findViewById(R.id.ad1);` like below code

```
RelativeLayout footer_lay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.footer_lay);

ad1= (ImageView) footer_lay.findViewById(R.id.ad1);
ad2= (ImageView) footer_lay.findViewById(R.id.ad2);
ad3= (ImageView) footer_lay.findViewById(R.id.ad3);
ad4= (ImageView) footer_lay.findViewById(R.id.ad4);
ad5= (ImageView) footer_lay.findViewById(R.id.ad5);
ad6= (ImageView) footer_lay.findViewById(R.id.ad6);
horizontalScrollView1=(HorizontalScrollView) footer_lay.findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
```

Comment: log cat is not getting posted here .. its huge

Comment: @AdvitiyaAbrol change `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`. i edited check out and try

Answer (score 1):

You just go wrong over here:

```
horizontalScrollView1 = (HorizontalScrollView) horizontalScrollView1
            .findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
```

replace this with below:

```
horizontalScrollView1 = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
ad1 = (ImageView) ad1.findViewById(R.id.ad1);
ad2 = (ImageView) ad2.findViewById(R.id.ad2);
ad3 = (ImageView) ad3.findViewById(R.id.ad3);
ad4 = (ImageView) ad4.findViewById(R.id.ad4);
ad5 = (ImageView) ad5.findViewById(R.id.ad5);
ad6 = (ImageView) ad6.findViewById(R.id.ad6);
horizontalScrollView1 = (HorizontalScrollView) horizontalScrollView1
            .findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
```

with:

```
ad1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad1);
ad2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ad2);
ad3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ad3);
ad4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ad4);
ad5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ad5);
ad6 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ad6);
horizontalScrollView1 =   
(HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
```